# I need to correct spelling errors but UPDATE gives a DML error

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to correct a couple of spelling mistakes in a specific column but I keep getting the error:

> DML over table 'tester-253410.test1.3foot' is not supported.

I had a look at the query settings and the following is not selected: Set a destination table for query results
This option is selected: Save query results in a temporary table

I only did the first part of the update so far:

```
UPDATE `tester-253410.test1.3foot`

SET string_field_0 = 'Galleria'

WHERE string_field_0 = 'GALLIERIA'
```

[screenshot settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m98Xy.png)

[screenshot settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q3En.png)

[screenshot settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Dym.png)

[TABLE DETAIL1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr6r3.png)

[TABLE DETAIL2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V14JQ.png)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your table properties from your BQ webUI which might shade some lights on this

Comment: I added 3 screenshots but they were turned into links by the uploader. Are these the settings that you refer to though?

Comment: I suspect your table is somewhat special, could you add a screenshot on your table detail page. Say, external table doesn't support DML and should throw this error.

Comment: I uploaded them and named them table detail1 and table detail2. Are these what you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

DML over external tables are not supported, thus the message

Instead, you can just do this text manipulation directly in Spreadsheet

Comment: In addition, here are some other [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#external_data_source_limitations) that may apply for external data sources. If you are planning on using BigQuery for more changes, you should consider creating a BigQuery native table and work with it.